# method() takes 1 positional argument, but 4 were given?

Tags: python, arguments

So this is my code, that uses recursion to solve the Tower of Hanoi, and this error comes up whenever I try to run `solve()`. The other function works fine *(I've tested it)*, and all of my methods contain `self`. I haven't found any similar error on SO, that don't have to do with someone forgetting `self`. So, why's this going wrong?

```
class RODS():
       pass 


class HANOI():

  def __init__(self,rings,start,end):
    self.rings=rings
    self.start=start
    self.end=end
    self.rods=RODS()
    for i in range(rings):
     setattr(self.rods,"rod"+str(i+1),[])
    self.rods.rod1=[1,2,3]
  
  def solve(self):
   if self.rings == 1:self.pm(self.start,self.end)
   else:
    other=6-(self.start+self.end)
    self.solve(self.rings-1,self.start,other)
    self.pm(self.start,self.end)
    self.solve(self.rings-1,other,self.end)

  def pm(self,start,end):
   rod=getattr(self.rods,"rod"+str(start+1))
   ring=rod[0]
   end_rod=getattr(self.rods,"rod"+str(end+1))
   end_rod.append(ring)
   rod.remove(ring)
   print("Ring:",ring,"-> Rod:",end)

  

hanoi=HANOI(3,1,3)
hanoi.solve()
```

This is the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 35, in <module>
    hanoi.solve()
  File "main.py", line 20, in solve
    self.solve(self.rings-1,self.start,other)
TypeError: solve() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

Comment: In your `solve()` function, you have `self.solve(self.rings - 1, self.start, other)` which passes 3 arguments to the `solve()` function, which is not matched by the parameters that `solve()` takes.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full traceback.

Comment: Done, sorry about that.

Comment: What version of Python are you on, btw? "solve() takes from 1 to 2 positional" doesn't seem right to me, when I run it on  I get the expected `TypeError: solve() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given`

Comment: It looks like the error message comes from a different version of the code, in which `solve` also had a parameter with a default value. Please make sure to provide the exact code you ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parameters for `solve`, but you probably are OK with default values for the top-level call:

```
def solve(self, start=1, stop=3, other=2):
   if self.rings == 1:
       self.pm(self.start, self.end)
   else:
       other = 6 - (self.start + self.end)
       self.solve(self.rings-1, self.start, other)
       self.pm(self.start, self.end)
       self.solve(self.rings-1, other, self.end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your method is not receiving any arguments and your are calling it again with 3 arguments and the method only expect the argument self.

```
    def solve(self):
        else:
            self.solve(self.rings-1,self.start,other) # 3 arguments + self argument = 4 arguments
```